# How do I get the CANCEL button to not execute a function that needs to be executed only when pressed OK on the dialogue box?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML table which displays a list of files in the system and its various other details. Now I want the filenames to be editable so that the user can rename the files if they wish to. I made `<input type="text"` and call `myRenameFunc()` function to display a pop-up box asking the user for consent (OK or CANCEL options). As you can see in my code my rename function is in JavaScript and I use `window.confirm()` to pop up a dialogue box.

Despite the user pressing CANCEL on the pop-up box, the function is still being called and the file is renamed. How I can get the CANCEL option to work without renaming the file?

```
print <<TABLEROW;
<td>
<input type="text" onchange="myRenameFunc()" name="old$filename" value="$filename"/>
</td>
TABLEROW

print <<MYSCRIPT;
<script>
function myRenameFunc(form) {

  var r;
  r = window.confirm("Rename Files?");

  if (r)
  {
    form.submit();
  }
  else
  {
    form.reset();
  }

  return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your question doesn't really relate to Perl. Its just about JavaScript.

Comment: Hi,yes it is. Do I have to post anything specific about it to be able to get answers?

Comment: I see no cancel or OK buttons. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @j08691 those are buttons that the browser generates via the `window.confirm()` javascript builtin. That thing returns `true` or `false` depending on the button the user clicks.